# Jquery ui automplete + json, Can't display "no result" in the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I tried to make autocomplete, but faced with a problem - I can't diplay "no result found". There were two problems: It displayed "no result" for 5 times or didn't display anything. Here the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#cities" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    $.ajax({
      url: "cities.json",
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
       response($.map(data, function(v,i){
            var text = v.City;
            if(text && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text))){
                return {
                    label: v.Id,
                    value: v.City
                };
            }else{  
                  value: "No result"
            }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 1,
  autoFocus: true
  });
});
```

I used the local json file, which contains this data:

```
[
{
"Id": 0,
"City": "Toronto"
},{
"Id": 1,
"City": "New-York" 
},{
"Id": 2,
"City": "Moscow"
},{
"Id": 3,
"City": "Monreal" 
},{
"Id": 4,
"City": "Vancouver"
},{
"Id": 5,
"City": "Williamsburg" 
}
]
```

Comment: If you have already json file then why you going to do ajax call ?

Comment: Do you required Accent folding ? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would think that returning no results would indicate to the user that "No Results Were Found". If the list shrinks or returns no entries, I feel pretty confident you won't have to indicate "No Results" to the user. But if you want to do this, there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

To return "No Result" you must pass an array of `[ "No Results" ]` to your `response` callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#cities" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
      var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
      $.ajax({
        url: "cities.json",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
          var results = [];
          $.each(data, function(k,v){
            var text = v.City;
            if(text && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))){
              results.push({
                label: v.Id,
                value: v.City
              });
            }
          });
          if(results.length == 0){
            results.push({ label: "No Results", value: null });
          }
          response(results);
        }
      });
    });
  },
  minLength: 1,
  autoFocus: true
  });
});
```